# Apache module shared memory object

Tags: c++, linux, apache, apache-modules

I am able to create shared memory segment containing struct using `apr_shm_create` problem is when I try to create class instance in this shared struct (segmentation fault). Is there any way to allocate custom object (and underlying data) in shared memory ? What I am trying to do is to create shared queue with strings between all apache processes.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use placement new operator (see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) but don't forget memory will not be mapped at the same address in any process, so you can't have pointers in objects in shared memory